# Securing inbuilt mysql service credentials with credhub on pcf

Tags: security, devops, cloud-foundry, credentials

I created a  mysql service using the pcf's mysql tile from marketplace. My app connects to this service using the VCAP_SERVICES in the application-cloud propeties.

I want to secure this mysql service credentials using credhub.

For a user proovided service , I used credhub as below and was able to secure the credentials.

```
cf create-service credhub default credhub-service -c '{"username":"admin","password":"admin"}'
```

How can the same be achieved for services which are not user provided and are created using the PCF tiles from marketplace.(mysql in my case)

Comment: As this question is about configuring server and database infrastructure and not about programming, it is off topic here on SO. Serverfault or dba sister sites of SO would be more suitable for this question.

Answer (score 0):

It's not something that an application developer can do. You need to talk to your operations team and have them enable that feature.

The relevant documentation can be found here: https://docs.pivotal.io/p-mysql/2-10/install-config.html#security-service-instance-creds

It explains how to enable that feature.